# Class Dependency - Can we use one Class in another Class, and vice versa as shown below which are inter dependent each other?

Tags: c#

```
public Class Calculation
{
  public double Rate{ get; set; }
  public double Amount{ get; set; }
  public int BranchId { get; set; }
  public Transaction transaction{ get; set; }
}

public Class Transaction
{
  public string ItemName{ get; set; }
  public string ItemQuantity{ get; set; }
  public Calculation calculatedTransaction{ get; set; }
}
```

Can we use one Class in another Class, and vice versa as shown which are inter dependent each other? Is that a good practice?

Comment: Yes, you can. What is the question?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Yes, because in C#, `class` variables have reference semantics, so there is an extra level of indirection. But you cannot do this with `struct`s, for they have value semantics. Btw, doing this would be a nightmare for serialization.

Comment: What keeps you away from writing a small programm with this two classes, use them and press compile/execute and watch the answer? The compiler will for sure answer this kind of questions

Comment: This isn't Class Dependency.  Both of these classes can be instantiated without the other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is absolutely nothing preventing you from doing that, it's even a very common scenario when working for example with entity framework and describing a 1:1 relationship

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the one class (say Calculation) to another class (say Transaction) linking to the same class (Calculation).

The one thing you cannot do is link add a reference of assembly which will cause circular dependency error. Other than that you can freely have any class reference as a member of any class. You can even have a class referencing to itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with this design, but it has one restriction: Both classes must reside in the same project forever. If you ever redesign your source code you cannot split your current project into smaller parts with separating those classes.

This is why you try to avoid it sometimes, by using interfaces.
You don't reference a concrete type, but an interface, and you can decide later, which class this interface implements. Can be your current class, can be in this project, can be in another project.

In scenarios like Entity Framework interfaces are not supported, but you group your data classes into the same project. Than it's OK.